# there exists open $\bar U \subset U$ satisfying $\psi|_{\bar U} = \phi|_{\bar U}$ .

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Let $\phi : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be continuous. Show that there exists a continuous function $\psi$, such that Support$(\psi) \subset U$ for a given
open set $U$ and there exists open $\bar U \subset U$ satisfying $\psi|_{\bar U} = \phi|_{\bar U}$ .

Need some hints to proceed with the problem.

Comment: Where does $\phi$ come into this? And for *any* set $\overline U$ whatsoever and *any* function $\psi$ that is defined on $\overline U, \psi\mid_{\overline U} = \psi\mid_{\overline U}$ since everything is equal to itself.

Comment: i have edited. ..

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1:

For any set $S \subseteq \Bbb R^n$, $d(x, S) = \inf \{d(x,s)\mid s\in S\}$ is a continuous function which is $0$ when $x\in \overline S$ and non-zero everywhere else.

Hint 2: (click in the yellow box to see)

> $\frac 1{1+d(x,S)}$ is $1$ on $\overline S$ and between $0$ and $1$ everywhere else

Hint 3:

> Given two sets $S, T$ with $d(S, T) = D > 0, \min\{\frac 1{1+d(x,S)}, \frac {d(x,T)}D\}$ is continuous, $=1$ on $\overline S$ and $=0$ on $\overline T$